# How to stop java application using a shell script

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script, which is run under a opensuse linux, that starts a java application (under a jar), the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
#PATH=/usr/local/java/bin:${PATH}

#---------------------------------#
# dynamically build the classpath #
#---------------------------------#
THE_CLASSPATH=
for i in `ls ./lib/*.jar`
do
  THE_CLASSPATH=${THE_CLASSPATH}:${i}
done

#---------------------------#
# run the application #
#---------------------------#
java -server -Xms512M -Xmx1G -cp ".:${THE_CLASSPATH}"  com.package.MyApp > myApp.out 2>&0 &
```

This script is working fine.

Now, what I want, is to write a script to kill gracefully this app, something that allows me to kill it with the -15 argument from Linux kill command.

The problem, is that there will be many java applications running on this server, so I need to specifically kill this one.

Any help?

Thanks in advance,

Fernando

Comment: Note your question, but you can/should put your app into a jar and just mention all of the libraries by relative path in its manifest file. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the PID of the backgrounded app somewhere useful.

```
echo $! > /var/lib/MyApp.pid
```

Then kill that PID in your other script.

Comment: Thanks @ignacio-vazquez-abrams, the resto of the answer was found here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884480/starting-and-killing-java-app-with-shell-script-debian

Answer (score 4):

Store the process ID in a file:

```
java ...blabla... &
echo $! > MyApp.pid
```

Then you can kill the JVM with `kill -TERM $(cat MyApp.pid)`.

Alternatively you can list the java processes on your system with `jps`. It lists the process ID and mainclass or jar file used to launch the application, which is probably enough to recognize your application. For example:

```
$ jps
20168 MyAPp
20186 Jps
$ kill -TERM 20168
```

More info on `jps`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html

Comment: Thanks @Joni Salonen, but I can't use jps. However it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ps xa` you can get the list of running processes including the full command used to start it.  If you do not want to use a temporary file like the others have mentioned, you can grep for java and also your class or jar name.

```
ps xa | grep java | grep com.package.MyApp | xargs kill -15
```